# get result by category with count for each category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this :

```
Categories
=================================
 Category |   subcategory   | Text 
---------------------------------
 film       English          The Lost World
 film       Hindi            sholai
 music      English          Enrique
 Music      Hindi            A.R Rahman
```

I want to categerize the result with their count.
the result should be like this

```
======================
  Category/    | count
 Sub Cate
 ----------------------
  film           2   
  music          2    
  english        2    
  Hindi          2
```

I want get the result like the follwing

Please help me to achive this

Thanks and Regards

Shibin

Comment: Will Category ever be the same as subcategory?

Comment: What in *diety* name did you write that question in? MS Word? I was going to edit it to make it more readable but.... no way.

Comment: category and subcat will be always differeent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Category AS 'Category/SubCategory', COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM  Categories
GROUP BY Category

UNION

SELECT SubCategory AS 'Category/SubCategory', COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM  Categories
GROUP BY SubCategory
```